# php combine arrays ignoring empty values

Tags: php, arrays

I am stuck.  I have 2 arrays that I want to combine, ignoring the empty values, and return a string.  Such as:

```
$Array1 ( [0] => [1] => Monday [2] => Wednesday [3] => Friday [4] => Sunday ) 
$Array2 ( [0] => [1] => 8am [2] => [3] => 10am [4] => [5] => 2pm [6] => [7] => 4pm )
```

to return:

> Monday 8am, Wednesday 10am, Friday 2pm, Sunday 4pm

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You can use array_filter(), if you haven't tried.

Comment: tried array_keys / array_values function to get rid of empty parts?

Answer (score 2):

```
$periods = array();
foreach (array_combine(array_filter($Array1), array_filter($Array2)) as $day => $hour) {
  $periods[] = $day . ' ' . $hour;
}
echo implode(', ', $periods);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely clear what format you want the output in, but using `array_filter()` is the first step:

```
$a1 = array( null, 'Monday', 'Wednesday', 'Friday', 'Sunday' );
$a2 = array( null, '8am', null, '10am', null, '2pm', null, '4pm' );

$a1 = array_filter($a1);
$a2 = array_filter($a2);
```

This removes the null entires. You can then use `foreach` to build your output. For an array of arrays:

```
$out = array();
foreach ($a1 as $e) $out[] = array($e, array_shift($a2));
```

For an array of strings:

```
$out = array();
foreach ($a1 as $e) $out[] = $e.' '.array_shift($a2);
```

Demo showing both output types: http://codepad.org/ITZJH4RL

Comment: array_filter() to remove the null entries was exactly what I was looking for.  The rest of my code worked just fine.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Kind of a dirty way to do it but..

```
//Your arrays:
$Array1 = array( null , Monday, Wednesday, Friday, Sunday) 
$Array2 = array(null, 8am, null, 10am,null, 2pm, null, 4pm)
$Array3 =();
foreach($Array2 as $key=>$val):
    if($val != ''):
        array_push($Array3, $val);
    endif;
endforeach;

// This assumes you have the same number of values in each array
foreach( $Array1 as $key=>$val):
   $Array1[$key] = $Array1[$key] . " " . $Array3[$key];
endforeach;

var_dump($Array1);
```

Give it a shot and let me know if you get any errors.

Edit: Turned example arrays into actual arrays instead of just listing them out from the example.

Comment: Yea, I know, I was just pulling in his arrays from his example.